# Advanced: Why ?function(){} works in R

Tags: r, interpreter

I understand some operators and functions in R need to be backquoted before using the help function. However, I don't understand why `?function(){}` also works. Does anyone have any idea on it?

Comment: It really isn't clear to me what your exact question is. Can you provide one or two concrete examples?

Comment: I would like to know how the R interpreter parse this statement here.

Comment: Also, I would like to know if there're any other special cases when using the help function in R. Cheers.

Comment: does the`?help` page answer your questions `Some topics need to be quoted (by backticks) or given as a character string. There include those which cannot syntactically appear on their own such as unary and binary operators, function and control-flow reserved words (including if, else for, in, repeat, while, break and next). The other reserved words can be used as if they were names, for example TRUE, NA and Inf.`

Comment: Hi @rawr, thank you for your help. Do you know what case ?function(){} satisfies here? Is it directly used as if it was name?

Comment: @YuliS yes it seems that is eventually the case

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Let's see what happens in `?`'s code using the {flow} package, it helps you inspect the logical path your code takes (follow the full lines):

```
flow::flow_run(?function(){}, out = "png")
```

[image]

We see that when the expression is a call we call `utils:::.helpForCall`

Let's see what happens there, we cannot call `flow::flow_run` directly so we call `flow::flow_debugonce` to set up `utils:::.helpForCall` and call `?` again

```
flow::flow_debugonce(utils:::.helpForCall, out = "png")
?function(){}
```

[image]

There we see that when the input is a call we call `utils:::.tryHelp` on the name of the function as a string. `function(){}` is a call to `function`
and `utils:::.tryHelp("function")` opens the help file.

---

Bonus

@rawr wonders why `?cars[1]` doesn't work, I haven't looked much into it but at a glance we see where the code takes a different path in `.helpForCall`:

```
flow::flow_debugonce(utils:::.helpForCall, out = "png")
?mtcars[1]
```

[image]

Comment: also interesting that `?x[1]` evaluates `x` but `?x[[1]]` does not? but that doesn't really have anything to do with this question ha..

Answer (score 3):

If you try

```r
debugonce(`?`)
?function(){}
```

you will arrive at this line

```r
if (is.call(topicExpr)) 
  return(.helpForCall(topicExpr, parent.frame()))
```

So calling

```r
debugonce(.helpForCall)
```

again will get to this line in `.helpForCall`

```r
f <- expr[[1L]]
```

If you examine `expr`, it is a `?call` with the following elements

```r
expr
# function() {
# }

as.list(expr)
# [[1]]
# `function`
# 
# [[2]]
# NULL
# 
# [[3]]
# {
# }
# 
# [[4]]
# function(){}
```

and

```r
class(expr[[1]])
# [1] "name"
```

Now, if you would ask me why

```r
?mtcars[1]
# Error in .helpForCall(topicExpr, parent.frame()) : 

?mtcars[[1]] ## works

?asdflasdflansldfnalsdf[1]
# Error in eval(argExpr, envir) : object 'asdflasdflansldfnalsdf' not found

?asdflasdflansldfnalsdf[[1]] ## works
```

I have no idea

Comment: Hi @rawr, thank you for your help as it provides me a very deep insight! Following your guidance, I've found that the expression mtcars[[1]] eventually becomes \`[[`. I'll dig deeper on this question in the future. BTW, it's very hard to decide whether I should accept your answer or moodymudskipper's one as both are very excellent answers.