# R: converting text with irregular length into dataframe

Tags: r, loops, readline

Simplified example of a text i have after importing with readlines:

```
text <- c("just", "stuff", "nothing", "interesting", "date", "06.05.2022", 
"number", "1/3892", "adress", "north street 45", "name", "peter miller", 
"just", "stuff", "nothing", "interesting", "date", "06.05.2022", 
"number", "5/7283", "adress", "south street 11, fareaway", "west street 4", 
"name", "john snow", "just", "stuff", "nothing", "interesting", 
"date", "06.05.2022", "number", "7/112563", "adress", "island street 348", 
"planet street 11, tortuga", "calvary road 9", "name", "hogson, michael", 
"jobs, steve", "just", "stuff", "nothing", "interesting", "date", 
"06.05.2022", "number", "2/1575", "adress", "bowland road 2, mexiko", 
"name", "michael myers", "terry jones", "olivia wilde", "just", 
"stuff", "nothing", "interesting", "date", "06.05.2022", "number", 
"1/93375", "adress", "sunset boulevard", "name", "harrison ford")
```

The same pattern is always repeating, I would like to have a dataframe like this:

| date | number | adress | name |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 06.05.2022 | 5/7283 | south street 11, fareaway, west street 4 | john snow |
| 06.05.2022 | 7/112563 | island street 348, planet street 11, tortuga, calvary road 9 | hogson, michael, jobs, steve |

There is always exact one date, one number, but one or more adresses and one or more names. "just stuff nothing interesting" is also always the same and can reliably be used the detect the end of the names.

I guess this could be achieved with loops, but I gave up on trying. Or is there a function which handles such irregularities? (not even sure if length is the right word for it, I hope it is clear what I mean...)

Comment: does 'name" always follow "address"?

Answer (score 3):

in Base R you could rewrite your text to a valid dcf and read it in.

```
x <- paste(text, collapse = ' ')
x <- gsub('just stuff nothing interesting', '', x)
x <- gsub('(name|number|adress)', '\n\\1:', x)
x <- gsub("date", "\n\ndate:", x)
read.dcf(textConnection(x), all = TRUE)

        date   number                                                     adress                                   name
1 06.05.2022   1/3892                                            north street 45                           peter miller
2 06.05.2022   5/7283                    south street 11, fareaway west street 4                              john snow
3 06.05.2022 7/112563 island street 348 planet street 11, tortuga calvary road 9            hogson, michael jobs, steve
4 06.05.2022   2/1575                                     bowland road 2, mexiko michael myers terry jones olivia wilde
5 06.05.2022  1/93375                                           sunset boulevard                          harrison ford
```

Note that you could run `cat(x)` to see what a valid dcf looks like

Using tidyverse:

```
text %>%
  str_replace("^(number|name|adress|date)", "\n\\1:") %>%
  str_replace("^(\ndate)", "\n\\1")%>%
  str_c(collapse = " ")%>%
  str_remove_all("just stuff nothing interesting") %>%
  textConnection()%>%
  read.dcf(all = TRUE)
```

Comment: At what point in the above `gsub` calls would `cat(x)`reflect the valid dcf? For those eyeballing it.

Comment: @Chris the last x. ie before using `read.dcf/textConnection`

Comment: And changing the record field from `adress` to `address`?

Comment: @Chris note that OP has `adress` everywhere. and not address. Meaning you will have to work with adress all the way and then change the column name to address

Comment: So, `names(df2)[3] <- 'address'`, very useful introduction to dcf.

Comment: This works perfectly even in my much more complex structure. But let's assume I want to have a possibility to separate the names later (for example: Show me only entries with exact two names), how could I do this? It seems like read.dcf has no option to do something different with multiple occurrences in a field.

Comment: Your question is confusing. Do you want  `separate` or `filter`?. Note that if the aswer posted here satisfies the question, consider accepting it

Comment: Sorry about the confusion. I just need a unique separator between multiple occurrences. Example output:

south street 11, fareaway/west street 4|john snow
island street 348/ planet street 11, tortuga/calvary road 9|hogson, michael/jobs, steve|

Answer (score 2):

Here's a piped version that works given the specification. It's worth pointing out that text parsing is very fragile to subtle differences in the input, so you may require a bit of work to get this functioning correctly with your real data.

Anyway, hopefully the concept is easy enough to follow:

```r
library(dplyr)

text %>% 
  paste(collapse = ' ') %>%
  strsplit('just stuff nothing interesting') %>%
  unlist() %>%
  `[`(nzchar(.)) %>%
  strsplit(' date | number | name ') %>%
  unlist() %>%
   `[`(nzchar(.)) %>%
  gsub(' adress', '', .) %>%
  matrix(nrow = 3) %>%
  t() %>%
  as.data.frame() %>%
  setNames(c('Date', 'Address', 'Name')) %>%
  as_tibble()
#> # A tibble: 5 x 3
#>   Date       Address                                                       Name 
#>   <chr>      <chr>                                                         <chr>
#> 1 06.05.2022 1/3892 north street 45                                        "pet~
#> 2 06.05.2022 5/7283 south street 11, fareaway west street 4                "joh~
#> 3 06.05.2022 7/112563 island street 348 planet street 11, tortuga calvary~ "hog~
#> 4 06.05.2022 2/1575 bowland road 2, mexiko                                 "mic~
#> 5 06.05.2022 1/93375 sunset boulevard                                      "har~
```

<sup>Created on 2022-05-06 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: And removing that pesky 'adress'?

Comment: @Chris just add a gsub - see my update